# Intelligent choice of basis

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be the vector space of all polynomials of degrees $\le 3$. Let $U$ be the subspace of polynomials of the form $a_3 x^3 + a_2 x^2$. Say you want to compute an orthogonal projection of some vector. I did a concrete example by picking any basis for $V$ and then using Gram Schmidt procedure to get an orthonormal basis. It was a long computation. Here the inner product is $$ \langle p,q \rangle = \int_0^1 pq (x) dx$$

Is there an intelligent way to pick an orthonormal basis for $V$? (intelligent=*not* blindly applying an algorithm invlolving so many calculations like Gram Schmidt)

Comment: I think that first you have to let us in on the secret of what inner product you are using.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Sorry for not writing it: $\langle p,q \rangle = \int_0^1 pq (x) dx$.

Comment: Good. But that information should be edited into the question, not hidden in the comments.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I'm sorry. I edited the question!

Comment: There's no need to have an orthogonal basis of $V$, an orthonormal basis of the subspace suffices to write down the projection of an arbitrary vector to it. Since your subspace has dimension 2, orthonormalization in that subspace isn't very much work (especially if you start with the basis $\{x^2,x^3\}$ for that subspace).

Comment: @celtschk That's what I did but I thought it was too much work.